# VBA - Adding a name inside the IF

Tags: vba, if-statement

I'm having some issue regarding the below code:

```
Sub Sendorders()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("Hugo Automate V15.xlsm")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Bid-Ask")

Dim i As Long

ws.Activate

ws.Cells(2, 20) = ws.Cells(2, 20) & " Equity"

For i = 8 To 242
 If ws.Cells(2, 20).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then

 If Cells(2, 23) = "BUY" Then
    Cells(i, 20) = Cells(2, 22)
    Cells(i, 21) = Cells(2, 21)
 Else
    Cells(i, 22) = Cells(2, 22)
    Cells(i, 23) = Cells(2, 21)
 End If
 End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I would like to compile the ligne 7 with the ligne 10 like this:

```
If ws.Cells(2,20) & "Equity".Value = ws.Cells(i,1).Value Then
```

However this doesn't work...

Comment: `If ws.Cells(2,20).Value & "Equity" = ws.Cells(i,1).Value Then` The added text isn't part of the range, thus you cannot use the value property after the string. Note that the standard property for a range is value, so `ws.Cells(2, 20)` is interpreted as `ws.Cells(2, 20).value`. So line 7 is technically already `ws.Cells(2, 20).value = ws.Cells(2, 20).value & " Equity"` But there's a differece in the two strings (a space), just so that you are aware.

Answer (score 0):

`.value` is a property of a Range object. It is also the default property used when looking at a range object.

As such, `ws.Cells(2,20)` from line 7 and `ws.Cells(2, 20).Value` from the `if` is the same thing.
Line 7 is therefore also this: `ws.Cells(2, 20).value = ws.Cells(2, 20).value & " Equity"`

The problem is trying to use the `.value` property, but not connected to the range object, but to the string: `ws.Cells(2,20) & "Equity".Value`, this will not work.

You can also you "With" instead of `Activate` to make sure you are targeting the right sheet, unless you specifically want to switch to that sheet.

```
With ws
   For i = 8 To 242
      If .Cells(2, 20).Value & " Equity" = .Cells(i, 1).Value Then
         If .Cells(2, 23) = "BUY" Then
            .Cells(i, 20) = .Cells(2, 22)
            .Cells(i, 21) = .Cells(2, 21)
         Else
            .Cells(i, 22) = .Cells(2, 22)
            .Cells(i, 23) = .Cells(2, 21)
         End If
      End If
   Next i
End with
```